# On a mac can I extend (not duplicate) my display to multiple external monitors?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, displayport

I've got a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) running Catalina 10.15.3 (cant upgrade OS since its a work laptop) and 3 external monitors. All 3 external monitors are connected and working fine.

All external monitors are connect via a HyperDrive GEN2 USB-C Hub 18-in-1. In particular the HyperDrive has 2 HDMI ports and 1 VGA port (all of which I am using). The HyperDrive is connected to my Mac via a USB-C port.

My MacBook has 4 x USB-C ports and seemingly no other ports.

I want to extend the display to all 3 monitors (like I can on Windows).

When I choose to extend the displays via ... System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement tab
and then uncheck "Mirror Displays" ... It extends the display on the laptop monitor to the 3 external monitors, however, the display on the 3 external monitors duplicates/mirrors the display on the other external monitors (but not the laptop monitor).

I don't want any of the displays to be duplicated! Is this possible on Mac out the box or is there any software to support this?

I read here ... https://hypershop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044788432-Does-the-12-or-18-port-allow-me-to-display-multiple-monitors- ... that:

> Mac OS only supports Single Stream Transport (SST) meaning it can only support one extended display over a single USB-C connection. The 2nd display will a mirror of the 1st display.

> Windows OS supports Multi-Stream Transport (MST) on supported computers and can support 3 extended displays over a single USB-C connection.

So I'm starting to lose hope that I can achieve what I want on my Mac which is 4 extended displays (including the laptop monitor). Any thoughts or help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out my MBP ports were TB3 ports not USB-C ports.

Herein Type C refers to a cable that supports USB-C and TB3.

I solved this by simply buying cables as follows:

External Monitor 1 ... Type C (MBP TB3 port) ---> HDMI Cable (Monitor)

External Monitor 2 ... Type C (MBP TB3 port) ---> HDMI Cable (Monitor)

THEN

Cable from MBP TB3 port ---> HyperDrive (Cable came with HyperDrive)

THEN

External Monitor 3 ... VGA (HyperDrive VGA port) ---> VGA Cable (Monitor)

AND

Voila - Monitor extends to all 4 displays (including laptop display).

**THE GENERAL RULE IS, USE 1 TB3 PORT PER MONITOR IF YOU WANT TO EXTEND YOUR DISPLAY TO THAT MONITOR.**

And I have 1 TB3 port left for the power. Perfect!

The only reason you need a HyperDrive at all is so that you have some ports for USB-A / USB-B devices, etc.

Generally speaking, you can purchases cables from any port type to any port type. I think they even do Type C to VGA if you need it!

I purchased my cables from Amazon Prime and they arrived next day. Companies I purchased cables from were UGreen and Uni. All cables purchased worked great. God is good! Jesus is amazing!

Comment: I’ll second the UNI recommendation, they are relatively new (to me at least) but worth checking out for the price point. Also monoprice is amazing in the non-Belkin adapter space. (Belkin are amazing, but cost a bit more)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up here. I want to do the exact same thing you're doing, but I think I'm SOL since my MBP only has 2 TB3 ports, not 4. Is there anything I can do? I've considered rolling back to a pre-Maverick OS but going all the way back to Mountain Lion feels like a bad idea...

Comment: not that I'm aware of sorry - sounds like the best you can do with extending your display is to 2 monitors (including laptop monitor) - of course you can duplicate with more monitors but that's not really helpful - unless of course there is some piece of hardware out there that I've never met that can help you - maybe u could buy an adapter or something that, instead of wasting a TB3 port on the power cable, you could share your power and a monitor on 1 of the TB3 ports - that would give u 3 monitors (including laptop monitor) if its possible

Comment: other ideas to free up a tb3 port ... could u remotely power you mac? i know u can remotely power iPhones, not sure its possible with a Mac but just throwing the idea out there ... or could you somehow power it through a hyperdrive? probably these ideas are not possible - but in your position I'd be thinking "I need to free up the TB3 port that the power cable is using"

Comment: Thanks. I've had the same thought re: freeing up the port I'm using for power, but even that would only get me to 2/3 of my external monitors working. Better than 1 for sure, but sub-opimal. Oh well

Comment: For anyone like me finding this answer more recently, it seems that this has not been fixed with Big Sur either, and Apple has no plans to do so

Comment: Update: You can power the computer through a dock and thereby get 2 of the three montiors working

Answer (score 1):

No, second screens are addressed as separate windows and not spanned. [You can run 6 plus displays on the macOS window manager](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406865/5472) even without external GPU, so it’s not about ports or cables or protocols. It’s the window manager design you’re fighting.

If you consider adding more pixels on a second or third display, then it’s trivial to add displays, just connect them. If you want a blended space where two displays extend into one logical contiguous space, that needs hardware or a different OS.  This came about in Mavericks and there’s no sign Apple is reversing decision on this.

- https://www.imore.com/how-span-window-between-two-displays-mavericks

The best you can do is in mission control, enable displays have their own spaces.

- [how to make each display a separate space, yet have a keyboard shortcut to move both screens at the same time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116557/how-to-make-each-display-a-separate-space-yet-have-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move)

You also might be very happy with an external GPU since it simplifies cable management and unlocks performance far past the MacBook Pro / Intel chipset alone can deliver.

Comment: bmike - whilst I'm sure you are right about everything you say - a practical example of a working setup would be nice

Comment: We use these as working setups all the time @danday74 and there’s no way I’m always right. Especially when I don’t know what you don’t know and vice versa. I’m not even sure I understand your definition of extend the display correctly after reading your answer. Thanks for putting one up!