# How many 27" Thunderbolt Displays does the 2020 M1 Mac mini support?

Tags: thunderbolt, mac-mini, thunderbolt-display, apple-silicon

[Apple's website](https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/) does state that ***"One display with up to 6K resolution at 60Hz connected via Thunderbolt"*** so it's probably not possible as per this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406864/does-the-2020-apple-m1-macbook-pro-support-2x-daisy-chained-thunderbolt-displays) regarding how M1 powered *MacBooks* supporting only a single 27" Thunderbolt Display as follows:
[image]

However, would an M1 Mac mini support dual 27" Thunderbolt Displays if connected as follows?

[image]

If they cannot be daisy chained via Thunderbolt 1 would a second Thunderbolt Adapter perhaps change things if used as follows:

[image]

I've seen how the [M1 can be connected up to 6x displays in total](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kq_FyjcAULA) using Display Link. However, I'm specifically interested in using the 2x 27" Thunderbolt displays I already have.

If you've got this working with a Mac mini, please share your experience. Thunderbolt 1x supported daisy chaining up to 6x 27" Thunderbolt displays and it would be very interesting to know if this is at all a possibility?

Comment: Please don't mark this as a duplicate as it pertains specifically to the Mac mini in this case, not the MacBook Pro.

Comment: Did you look here: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP823?locale=en_US ? It specifically shows several methods of hooking up 2 displays in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those two suggested display configurations are possible, I'm afraid. You can only connect 1 of the 27" Thunderbolt displays to the Thunderbolt 3 ports on the M1 Mac Mini. It doesn't matter if you daisy chain two monitors or plug them into each of their own Thunderbolt 3 ports - it still won't work.

The only way to natively hook up 2 displays to the M1 Mac Mini is to drive one display (and one display only) through the Thunderbolt 3 port and the other through the HDMI port. Obviously the 27" Thunderbolt Display does not connect with the HDMI port.

When I say natively, I mean that it is ofcourse possible to use non-native display options - most popular would be a variety of DisplayLink products.

Adapters such as [this](https://www.siig.com/hdmi-to-usb-c-port-4k-60hz-converter-adapter.html) do exist that converts the HDMI output to a USB-C style DisplayPort output. I guess you could plug a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter into that, but I doubt that it would work.

Comment: Thank you, I'm hopeful that future versions of Apple Silicon Macs will support this.

Comment: I would find it extremely likely that this is supported by the next batch of Apple Silicon Macs... however, I doubt that it would ever be supported on the M1-based Macs.